# Mapping entities for Sql Server Identity and Oracle Sequence with NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a application that uses `C#` and `NHibernate` and it will support `SQL Server 2008`, `SQL Server 2012` and `Oracle`. I have been using fluent nhibernate to map my entities and I have some questions about how should I map the ID. Oracle supports only the Sequence, SQL Server 2008 only identity and Sql Server 2012 both. I would like to map in Sql Server (2008 and 2012) with Identity and Oracle with Sequence on the same code.

*How should I map the ID to work for all databases?*

It does not matter if I will have some IF's statement on my fluent mapping code. Looks my codes for mapping:

For SQL:

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
```

For Oracle:

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Sequence("SQ_Customer");
```

**PS: I do not want any workaround to achieve it. I want a `NHibernate/Fluent-NHibernate` solution to map it.**

Comment: Do you have to wait for database to give you the id, or can you generate your own using nhibernates HILO generator?

Comment: I was think using a Guid but unfortunately I can not change my database :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, "Native" chooses Identity, sequence or HILO automatically depending on the used DB.

Using this xml mapping it should use identity or the sequence `sq_customer` if its Oracle:

```
  <generator class="native" >
    <param name="sequence">sq_customer</param>
  </generator>
```

[This post](http://thatextramile.be/blog/2007/07/native-id-generation-with-nhibernate/) describes things further.

Comment: It's the correct answer. Translated to Fluent: `Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native("SQ_Customer");`

Comment: Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Increment() works without needing a sequence.

Comment: I was searching 2 days for solution in Java. No answers like that for Java. No info in doc. This "trick" helped me very much, worked perfectly for MS SQL Identity and Oracle SEQUENCE-TRIGGER. Thank you very much.

Comment: great I was of assistance, vote up the answer if you don't mind :)